# Pandas conditionally merge dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
col1 col2 col3 col4 
0    31    53   82
1    23    73   32 
2    35    34   12 
3    36    13   24 
4    23    93   36 

df2:
col1 col5  col6  col7  
2    315   324   122 
3    316   123   224 
4    213   923   326
```

I want to merge the two dataframes, but want to delete some columns i don´t need. although the rows with index which is not in both df should be deleted.

```
df3:
col1 col2 col4 col5  col7 
2    35    12  315   122 
3    36    24  316   224 
4    23    36  213   326
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop unwanted columns and merge on `col1`.

```
df = df1.drop(['col3'], 1).merge(df2.drop(['col6'], 1), on='col1')
df

   col1  col2  col4  col5  col7
0     2    35    12   315   122
1     3    36    24   316   224
2     4    23    36   213   326
```

You can add more columns to drop inside the list arguments as needed.